# print webpage in css a4 size

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

when I want to print my webpage  I have a problem  everything is changed on the print page and I want to print a webpage like a[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPBcp.png) screen I have it

Comment: You should use a separate CSS for the print layout.

Answer (score 0):

A4 size in pixels is **3508(width)px ,2480(height)px**

so you can make a **media query** for print mode.

```
@media print{
   
   body{
       width: 3508px;
       height: 2480px;
       font-size: 33px;
   }
   
}
```

This is simple example.

see more *@media print* go to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: thanks but I do that doesn't work :>

Comment: What happens when you do this method? Please upload a picture(print mode) and see.